# Error with database in javafx DataApp demo

Tags: java, sql, javafx

The DataApp included in the [javafx demos](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) example comes with an ant script to create and populate a database with MySQL. After configuring the MySql connector it is only a matter of calling an ant task:

```
<target name="-post-init" >
    <input message="Please enter Mysql password for root@localhost:" addproperty="mysql.password"/>
    <!-- first create user and database -->
    <echo>Creating "dataapp" user and "APP" database...</echo>
    <sql    driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:4447/mysql"
            userid="root"
            password="mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar"
            classpath="${libs.MySQLDriver.classpath}"
            >
        DELETE FROM user WHERE User = 'dataapp';
        DELETE FROM db WHERE User = 'dataapp';
        INSERT INTO user VALUES ('localhost','dataapp','*B974A83D18BB105D0C9186756F485406E6E6039B','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','','','','',0,0,0,0,'',NULL);
        INSERT INTO db VALUES ('localhost','APP','dataapp','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','N','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','N','Y');
        DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS APP;
        CREATE DATABASE APP;
        FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
    </sql>
    <echo>Creating tables and views...</echo>
    <sql    driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/APP"
            userid="dataapp"
            password="dataapp"
            classpath="${libs.MySQLDriver.classpath}"
            src="${basedir}/create-database.sql"/>
    <echo>Populating zip code table(this might take a little while)...</echo>
    <sql    driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/APP"
            userid="dataapp"
            password="dataapp"
            classpath="mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar"
            src="${basedir}/zip_code_inserts.sql"/>
</target>
```

However, I am getting this exception when I run it:

```
  [sql] Failed to execute:  INSERT INTO user VALUES    ('localhost','dataapp','*B974A83D18BB105D0C9186756F485406E6E6039B','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','','','','',0,0,0,0,'',NULL)
```

With this exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

I think that the number of fields is not what it should be, but I am no MySQL expert, so I don't know how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of columns that the 'user' table has seems to change from one version of MySQL to the next one. I was able to find the correct number by logging into the MySQL console, and do:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` WHERE table_name = 'user' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mysql';
```

Then I used:

```
SELECT * FROM user;
```

to see what where the values for my own user and copy those, the correct command for:

```
Server version: 5.1.61-community-log
```

was:

```
INSERT INTO user VALUES ('localhost','dataapp','*B974A83D18BB105D0C9186756F485406E6E6039B','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','','','','','0','0','0','0');
```