# How do I fix this: Ant cannot "find file" when trying to build a Java web application on Jenkins?

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, jenkins, ejb

I am trying to set up an automatic build system with Jenkins CI for a NetBeans multitiered web application project. This NetBeans project contains an EJB-project (for the business layer of the web application) and a WAR-project (for the web layer of the application). I'm currently stuck on getting Ant to compile the project.

I am using Windows 8 to develop in NetBeans IDE 8.0. Jenkins also runs on Windows 8.

I'm currently looking for someone who understands how to build EJB-projects with Jenkins and Ant.

**What I've done so far:**

- I've set up a NetBeans project (as described above)
- I've set up a git repository for the project
- I've set up Jenkins CI
- I am able to get the project from the git repository with Jenkins CI
- I am able to make Jenkins use Ant to clean the project it retrieved
  from the git repository

**Where I get stuck:**

After being succesful to execute the *clean* command with Ant I want to make the *debug* command work. For this the project needs to be compiled. Here is where it goes wrong.

I entered the following properties in the Properties field for the Ant Invoke in Jenkins:

```
libs.CopyLibs.classpath=C:/Program Files/NetBeans 8.0/java/ant/extra/org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar
j2ee.server.home=C:/Program Files/wildfly-8.1.0.Final
```

In the output of my Jenkins build I see the following command:

*[PGB Webapp] $ cmd.exe /C '""C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Ant_AntInstallation\Apache_Ant\bin\ant.bat" "-Dlibs.CopyLibs.classpath=C:/Program Files/NetBeans 8.0/java/ant/extra/org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar" "-Dj2ee.server.home=C:/Program Files/wildfly-8.1.0.Final" clean debug && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"'*

And this is the last part of my output: (the part that seems most important to me)

```
init:

-init-cos:

-deps-module-jar:

-deps-ear-jar:

deps-jar:

-pre-pre-compile:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\pgb-ejb\build\classes

-pre-compile:

-copy-meta-inf:
     [copy] Copying 2 files to C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\pgb-ejb\build\classes\META-INF

-do-compile:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\pgb-ejb\build\empty
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\pgb-ejb\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
    [javac] Compiling 5 source files to C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\pgb-ejb\build\classes

-post-compile:

compile:

-pre-dist:

library-inclusion-in-manifest:

BUILD FAILED
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\nbproject\build-impl.xml:204: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\pgb-ejb\nbproject\build-impl.xml:806: Warning: Could not find file C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\pgb-ejb\${libs.MySQLDriver.classpath} to copy.

Total time: 1 second
Build step 'Start Ant' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

So in this output I see the following warning:

*Warning: Could not find file C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\pgb-ejb\${libs.MySQLDriver.classpath} to copy.*

Now, to me this seems to be a rare issue as I can find almost nothing about it on the internet (or am I using the wrong search term?) I've searched on Google, here on SO, and DuckDuckGo, and I could only find the following (pretty useless) clues to my problem: (pretty useless because the warning I get is mentioned there, but the context is different..)

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=128505 and [Error with database in javafx DataApp demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138387/error-with-database-in-javafx-dataapp-demo)

Any help is appreciated as I am still pretty new to continuous integration systems, developing web applications and build tools.

Also, I haven't looked much into Maven or Gradle yet as alternatives. So maybe the solution to the problem might as well be to switch to another build tool..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me as if the property libs.MySQLDriver.classpath is not defined.
When Ant cannot resolve a property, it uses the property name in the output.

Try to define

```
libs.MySQLDriver.classpath
```

in the properties field in Jenkins where you also defined the other two properties.

You need to point it to your MySQL JDBC driver.

Comment: Thanks, solved it! I added the property like this: libs.MySQLDriver.classpath=C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Connector J/mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar